# Meteor subscribing to the same publication on different routes, are cursors re-run for each route?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

When two routes within a meteor application subscribe to the same publication, are the cursors within the publication re-run when the user switches between these routes?

If so, How can I prevent this because it is unnecessary.

As this publication is in high usage across the app on most routes, is it worth subscribing from the app body (globally)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using iron:router?

You can use something like:

```
Router.configure({
   waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('sub'); }
})
```

This is one technique for a global publication.

Comment: Yes, Im using iron router. I would like to know more about if they are re-run on every route change

Comment: From what I know, they "are re-run" on every change.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't re publish if your routes are subscribing to the same publisher. 
by adding subscription management to your client you can make sure that client's browser will keep the data for a period of time so if user came back to the page or another route needs the subscription, the app don't need to get the same data again.